# 'int' object is not callable problem on python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, i'm writing this code and i'm totally new to python btw, my code is based on solving this maths problem which involves the expression (a+b)^2

As I hit built, an error surfaced stating

```
"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"
```

I don't know where it went wrong, I would be highly greatful if someone told me where I went wrong and how to rectify it. Thank You :)

This is my code :

```
def sub():
    return 1 ^ 2 + 2(1 * 2) + 2 ^ 2


print(9 ^ 2 + 2(9 * 8) + 8 ^ 2)
```

Comment: `2(1 * 2)` should be `2 * (1 * 2)`.

Comment: Also, the power operator in Python is `**`, not `^`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I've corrected your code.

```
def sub():
    return 1 ^ 2 + 2*(1 * 2) + 2 ^ 2


print(9 ^ 2 + 2*(9 * 8) + 8 ^ 2)
```

Moreover, **^** is **xor** operator. If you want to find the power then user ** instead.

Comment: found what I heard I, did not expect any reply but thanks a lot Sohan for helping me out really means a lot  god bless you

Answer (score 0):

**2(1 * 2)**   this part of the statement is throwing an error because you didn't specify any arithmetic symbol between **2**  and **(1 * 2)**.  since python doesn't understand general mathematics operations as we use in books(according to mathematics it is * or multiply operation but according to python it's call on int(**2**)).

```
def sub():
    return 1 ^ 2 + 2*(1 * 2) + 2 ^ 2


print(9 ^ 2 + 2*(9 * 8) + 8 ^ 2)
```

try this.

Comment: found what I heard I, did not expect any reply but thanks a lot Jivan for helping me out really means a lot  god bless you

Answer (score 0):

^ is not square and ( will not multiply.

Function implementation:

```
def sub(a, b):
    c = (a**2)+(2*a*b)+(b**2)
    return c

print(sub(1,2))
```

Normal Calculation:

```
print((9 ** 2) + (2 *9 * 8) + (8 ** 2))
```

Comment: found what I heard I, did not expect any reply but thanks a lot Vignesh for helping me out really means a lot  god bless you

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved @PrathamChawla